# Which performance metrics (F1 Score, ROC AUC, PRC, MCC Score) can help me assess my model's performance on an imbalanced dataset?

Tags: logistic-regression, text-classification, roc, precision-recall, imbalanced-data

I am working on a text classification problem with a highly imbalanced dataset. I'm in a dilemma of choosing between performance metrics. I cannot figure out which matrix would be wise to choose amongst these four (ROC AUC, PRC AUC, F1, MCC) measures. Also, there's variety in each type like threshold and probability.
Since these all have different outcomes how do I understand which performance metrics would be best fit for my model and I can get an insight of whether my model is successfully working or not?

Dataset Information:

```
class 1 - 98%
class 0 - 2%
```

I have applied various performance metrics for Logistic Regression and got these results:

```
Accuracy - 0.9824
Precision - 0.9807
Recall - 0.9824
F1 score - 0.9813

ROC AUC score - 0.6151
ROC AUC score (using predict_proba method on the classifier) - 0.9902

PRC AUC score - 0.9655
MCC score - 0.6021
```

I have also calculated f1 score for separate classes

```
F1 score for 1 - 0.9910
F1 score for 0 - 0.6021
```